# Why doesn't apply work on DOM element functions?

Tags: javascript, dom

Sample code

```
document.body.getAttribute.apply(this,['id']);
document.body.setAttribute.apply(this,['id','test']);
```

The error
Firefox:

> TypeError: 'setAttribute' called on an object that does not implement interface Element.

Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(this)`, because Firefox's error message clearly shows that `this` is not an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` is working just fine. It is calling the `setAttribute` function and inside that function the value of `this` is what you set it to).

We can't see what it is you are setting it to because you are passing `this` without showing us what its value is.

Clearly, `this` is not a DOM element, so you can't set a DOM attribute on it.

If you had called `document.body.getAttribute()` then inside `setAttribute` the value of `this` would be `document.body`, which is a DOM element.

You can see it working if `this` is a DOM element in this example:

```js
document.querySelector('div').setID = function () {
    document.body.setAttribute.apply(this,['id','test']);
}

document.querySelector('div').setID();
document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = document.querySelector('div').id;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: That explains it. In my code I used the apply inside an Array.map function so `this` referenced the new function.

Answer (score 2):

This works :

```
document.body.setAttribute.apply(document.body,['id','test']);
document.body.getAttribute.apply(document.body,['id']);
```

In your code (if you execute outside any function), `this` refers to the window element, so your code is equivalent to :

```
window.setAttribute("id","test");
```

which is not allowed

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason why you need `apply`? As `this` is your window object. Applying an `id` to it is probably not very useful or even allowed. From what I know, I would go with this method:

```
document.body.getAttribute('id');
document.body.setAttribute('id','test');
document.body.getAttribute('id');
```

Feel free to correct me :)

Comment: Thank you, this is simple & complete. Was struggling to get this simple code.